# combine data in list based on location value in python

Tags: python

I have lists in Python. Simple representation is as below with title Input. How can I identify 2 term location( Eg 'las' 'vegas')  and combine  them to achieve a location with single term( eg 'lasvega') . Desired output as show below order of input list is always randomized.  Any pointers on how I can achieve will be appreciated.

**Input:**

```
['vegas' , 'hotel' , 'las']
['new' , 'york' , 'flights']
['san' , 'accomodations' , 'franscisco']
['san' , 'diego' , 'motel']
```

**Desired output:**

```
['lasvegas' , 'hotel' ]
['newyork' , 'flights']
['sanfranscisco' , 'accomodations' ]
['sandiego' , 'motel']
```

Comment: Are they in any particular order? If not, what do you expect to be able to do? Importantly, **what have you tried?** See [ask]

Comment: they can be in any random order. Idea is to identify location which has split , combine them.  So tht unique locations can be identified in each list. I have explored a bit in python but unable to crack exact logic yet

Comment: How would you identify them? Do you have an external source of strings which are known-valid city names?

Comment: I will have through go through the dataset manually , build a list of possible 2 term location. I have about 0.5 million such rows. with most locations repeating I will group them to identify highly occurring location pair .

Comment: OK, so have you tried that? Did it work? What are you asking for with this post?

Comment: Yes I have identified most of the 2 term locations. My ask through this post is  to identify 2 term location in each list if they are present and  combine them. Is there any reference on how I can achieve that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that information. It's very unclear as is.

Comment: Sure. Tried to make a little bit more edit.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is full-text search. If the dataset you have is really large or there are performance concerns, you should consider a tailor-made solution like `Elastic Search` or `Solr` or som suitable database.

If you only want a simple solution in Python, then you first need to maintain a dictionary of all the cities in the world. After that you can find all combinations of strings in list i.e. powerset of the list and loop over the powerset to find which combinations exist in before mentioned city dictionary.

Comment: I prefer doing in Python. I shall explore option you suggested.